# Rotating image around a point

Tags: raphael

I'm trying to solve this one for hours and I can't figure out where I am going wrong..

On my page there is an image and a "selection frame". This frame can be moved and resized. 
I am trying to make the image turn with the center point of the turn being the center of the frame.

I created a small handle at the top for rotation.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8PhqX/7/ (give it a minute to load)

The code in the fiddle is very long because I couldn't isolate the specific area relevant to my question. As you play around with it you'll see that the first rotation usually works fine, but then, things go crazy.

Here's the codeline for the rotation:

```
//selfRotator.handle.angle is the angle(clockwise) at which the rotation handle was       rotated
//selfSelector.rotator.ox/oy is the position of the middle of the selection frame
//selfDefaults.imageArea.y is the y position of the section with the image (because of the red stripe in the top)
//selfImageArea.page.startX/Y is starting position of the image storing its position when the drag begins
//rotating by angle, at center point of selection
selfImageArea.page.transform(
['r', -selfRotator.handle.angle, selfSelector.rotator.ox - selfImageArea.page.startX,    selfSelector.rotator.oy - (selfImageArea.page.startY - selfDefaults.imageArea.y)]
)
//tracking the image's start position and compensating 
selfImageArea.page.attr({
transform: "...T" + (selfImageArea.page.startX) + "," + (selfImageArea.page.startY - selfDefaults.imageArea.y)
});
```

It looks like it gets messed up because of the getBBox values that don't follow the picture outlines.

I've added gridlines to illustrate the problem

also, iv'e came across this code(https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/raphaeljs/b8YG8DfI__g) for "getBBoxRotated()" function that should solve my issue but I can't seem to implement it.

Comment: It will probably be ok as long as rotate back to upright, the question is what do you actually want it to do if you rotate around one point, leave it rotated and shift it, and then rotate it around another. Its not an easy one to get your head around, so difficult to solve. Is there a reason you don't want to rotate just around its centre, as it would make it a lot simpler ? Otherwise I think you will have to add multiple transforms, or start building a matrix to keep track. I may be wrong though.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's a pretty elaborate task, but as you can see, the first rotation works fine...

Comment: Yep, the first rotation works fine, as there's only one rotation to take into account, after two rotations, you need to take into account the first rotation as well, hence it makes it quite a bit more complicated. Off the top of my head, I think you may need to combine the existing matrix with the new transformation each time.

Comment: I think the problem is with the manipulation of the getBBox. 
I updated the fiddle code and added gridlines to illustrate the problem. see the edited question.. maybe you could help out?

Comment: Its not clear (to me) still what you are trying to do. Are you just trying to do a free transform, or something else (as not sure why). Suppose you rotate by 45deg, then drag the controller by 300,300, then rotate by 45deg. How much do you want (the already rotated image) to be rotated by, and around what in total? I think you'll probably have to store the transformation.

Comment: Did you try the fiddle? 
I am logging the angle and position but the getBBox, doesn't return the new positions of the corners of the picture, instead they return (as expected) the bounding box.

Comment: If thats the bit thats missing, as its an image (ie a rect), the transformed bounding box will just be a transformation on the points of the image won't it anyway ? I'd be tempted to break it down into one small subset problem (ie how do you find the positions of a transformed image), and repost the question.

Comment: That's the problem.. the bounding box stays parallel to the x,y axis. 

Look at the fiddle. the blue lines around the picture represent the bounding box...

But your right. i'll try to re post
here's the link to the new post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363633/finding-the-coordinates-of-a-rotated-image-in-raphael